# How to make an Encode function based on this Decode function?

Tags: c#, byte, xor, bitwise-operators

How to make an Encode function based on this Decode function?
I got the source code for the Decode function on the internet but I need the Encode function.

All my attempts to make it failed and the original coder isn't available at the moment.

The (original) code:

```
byte Decode(byte EncodedByte)
{
    EncodedByte ^= (byte)194;
    EncodedByte = (byte)((EncodedByte << 4) | (EncodedByte >> 4));
    return EncodedByte;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
byte Encode(byte EncodedByte) 
{ 
    EncodedByte = (byte)((EncodedByte << 4) | (EncodedByte >> 4)); 
    EncodedByte ^= (byte)194; 
    return EncodedByte; 
}
```

Comment: I didn't knew it's this easy. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Just some quick back of the napkin coding the answer should be

```
byte Encode(byte DecodedByte)
{
    DecodedByte = (byte)((DecodedByte << 4) | (DecodedByte >> 4));
    DecodedByte ^= (byte)194;
    return DecodedByte;
}
```

Also I agree with Alex this is a trivial Encryption method. Anyone who knows the algorithm can trivially decrypt your message. I would not rely on it for any sensitive information and if this is code for public use some countries have laws that data must have some form of encryption. If I was a judge for the person suing you for a data breach I would call this more of a obfuscation technique then a encryption technique.

Comment: Thank you, Henrik was first though. +1.

Comment: Came up with the same myself - ran a unit test on all possible bytes and it successfully works (as if you had a doubt ;))

Comment: Henrik and I posted about 15 seconds apart. If I had not changed my EncodedBytes to Decoded bytes I would have been first ;p

Comment: About your edit, I agree. I'm dealing with a file format that I didn't make so I can't really do anything about it.

Comment: Sorry for not accepting your answer. But you've got 3 upvotes. :P

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you use normal encryption/decryption functions of c#?

[Encrypt and decrypt a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-decrypt-string-in-net)

Comment: Why would I? This code is converted from C++ and this way works perfect. Also, I have no idea how I would convert this to 'normal encryption/decryption functions'.

Comment: This isn't very helpful - he's likely dealing with data created through some other process that has to use this approach.

Comment: Indeed, see Scott's answer's comments.